# what time is 'second stroke of midday'?

Tags: meaning

I was watching an American drama and I heard 'second stroke of midday'

When is second stroke of midday?

Does it indicate a specific time???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stroke](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stroke://) in the sense of:

> [ C ] one of the sounds that some clocks make at particular times, especially by ringing a bell once for each number of the hour:
>
> - *How many strokes did you count?*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

The second stroke is just the secon in line  of the twelve strokes of midday and the time is exaclty  12 AM.

Comment: In fact, the word "clock" is derived from a Medieval Latin word meaning "bell." See German "glocke" and French "cloche" for cognates to "clock." In the early Middle Ages, Europe told time by bells rather than mechanical clocks.